# Updates and Inserts happens in Target table needs to get flagged in Source table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Source Table Name: SAP_Load.

Target Table Name: Premise

I would like to update and Insert the records from "SAP_Load" to "Premise table".

There are 2 fields in SAP_Load -  "Transaction_Flag" and "Status"

As soon as the updates and inserts happens in the target table, then the "Transaction_Flag" and "Status" from the Source table gets updated as per the below mentioned two conditions

1] AFter Updates

```
UPDATE [SDE].[SAP_Load] SET
    Transaction_Flag = 1
    , Status= 1
where pt.Premise_ID = s.Premise_ID;
```

2] After Inserts

```
UPDATE [SDE].[SAP_Load] SET
    Transaction_Flag = 2
    , STATUS= 1
where Premise_ID = s.Premise_ID;
```

I have explained my case here: Please look at it. I am getting an error over two places.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=71671ecd8e4ff1bf805c453e012d6a75

Actual Code:

```
    CREATE TABLE sde.SAP_Load (
        Premise_ID nvarchar(50),
        Division nvarchar(15),
        InstallationType nvarchar(12),
        Transaction_Flag Integer,
        Status Integer
    );
    
    CREATE INDEX Source
    ON sde.SAP_Load (Premise_ID, Division, InstallationType);
    
    INSERT INTO sde.SAP_Load
    VALUES 
    ('8000004592', 'WT', 'WATR', '', ''),
    ('8000004592', 'WT', 'IRRG', '', ''),
    ('8000004592', 'SW', 'WWTR', '', ''),
    ('8000004593', 'WT', 'IRRG', '', ''),
    ('8000004594', 'SW', 'WWTR', '', '');

    CREATE TABLE sde.Premise (
        OBJECTID bigint NOT NULL,
        Premise_ID nvarchar(50),
        Division nvarchar(15),
        InstallationType nvarchar(12),
    );
    
    CREATE INDEX index_name_Premise
    ON sde.SAP_Load (Premise_ID, Division, InstallationType);
    
    INSERT INTO sde.Premise
    VALUES 
    ( '1', '8000004592', 'SW', 'WWTR'),
    ('2', '8000004592', 'WT', 'WATR');

UPDATE pt WITH (UPDLOCK, SERIALIZABLE) 

  SET   InstallationType = s.InstallationType,
        Division = s.Division
  FROM sde.Premise AS pt
  INNER JOIN sde.SAP_Load AS s
    ON pt.Premise_ID = s.Premise_ID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE [SDE].[SAP_Load] SET Transaction_Flag =1, Status= 1 where pt.Premise_ID = s.Premise_ID;

    DECLARE @oid bigint;
    SELECT @oid = MAX(OBJECTID) FROM sde.PREMISE;
    
    INSERT sde.Premise(OBJECTID, InstallationType, Premise_ID,  Division)
      SELECT COALESCE(@oid, 0) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID),
          s.InstallationType, s.Premise_ID, s.Division
        FROM sde.SAP_Load AS s
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sde.PREMISE
          WHERE Premise_ID = s.Premise_ID
        AND InstallationType = s.InstallationType
        AND Division = s.Division);


    UPDATE sde.Premise SET OBJECTID += @oid;

    UPDATE [SDE].[SAP_Load] SET Transaction_Flag =2, STATUS= 1 where Premise_ID = s.Premise_ID;
```

My expected result is

[image]

Comment: 1) `WHEN MATCHED` is only valid for a `MERGE` statement, not an `UPDATE` statement. 2) `s.Premise_ID` doesn't exist in your `UPDATE` hence the error. You'd need to explain where it should be coming from.

Comment: There are so many syntax errors that we probably need to start afresh. What are your expected results?

Comment: And you seem to be trying to do a diy identity. This is prone to issues due to concurrency and race conditions.

Comment: @Charlieface: I have added my expected result.